# how to set a shader color both from top to bottom and from left to right in a CAGradientLayer?

Tags: ios, shader, cagradientlayer

I want to draw a UiView's background use shader color.So I find the QuartzDemo.But I want to set the shader from white to red at horizontal and from white to black at vertical direction.
What can I do that ???
Need you help.Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Use two layers with transparency?

Comment: If use two layers then I can not pick color in it.I find a easy Demo that match me.https://github.com/ricktrapp/GradientPicker